# Unable to integrate Redis with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redis, codeigniter-2

I am using [codigniter-redis](https://github.com/joelcox/codeigniter-redis) library to use redis inside the codeigniter framework. I've put [Redis.php](https://github.com/joelcox/codeigniter-redis/blob/develop/libraries/Redis.php)( library file ) in applications/library and [redis.php](https://github.com/joelcox/codeigniter-redis/blob/develop/config/redis.php)( config file ) in applications/config

Here is my code

```
class Test extends Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        log_msg('info', "loading redis");
        $this->load->library('redis', array('connection_group' => 'default'), 'redis_default');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->redis->command('PING');
    }
```

When I call test controller from browser it gives me error

```
Message: Undefined property: Test::$redis

Filename: controllers/test.php
```

But it shows appropriate logs in log file, one which is shown above and one I put in Redis.php function _construct which tells me that the connection is successful

```
if ( ! $this->_connection)
        {
            show_error('Could not connect to Redis at ' . $config['host'] . ':' . $config['port']);
        }
        else
        {
            log_msg('info', "connection successful");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to double check: the code you posted here, is that exact from the controller?
If that is so, please remember to extend from CI_Controller, not just Controller.

Also, in the _*construct(), you are missing your parent::*_construct().

From you're log entries, it shows that it is connecting on the _*construct(), but that is basically where it ends. Most probably caused by the missing parent::*_construct(). Hope this helps